# Use arange to generate an array containing all the decades from 1940 to 2020

Tags: python, datetime, data-science

Using Numpy, how can i produce an array that looks like this:
`array(['1940', '1950', '1960', '1970', '1980', '1990', '2000', '2010', '2020'], dtype='datetime64[Y]')`

Comment: Take a look here [numpy arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

Comment: If you already know which function to use (NumPy's `arange`), why don't you try using that function and see what happens? Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy

numpy.arange(numpy.datetime64("1940"), numpy.datetime64("2030"), numpy.timedelta64(10, "Y"), dtype='datetime64[Y]')
```

Take a look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html for how to use `numpy.arange()`.

Also, look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html?highlight=datetime64 for how to use `numpy.datetime64` and `numpy.timedelta64`.

Comment: Note that the OP asked for datetime objects, not integers. Also, you could also link to the docs for this function.